# How to run clustering with categorical variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science

I'm trying to run clustering only with categorical variables. Since Kmeans is applicable only for Numeric data, are there any clustering techniques available?

I have 30 variables like zipcode, age group, hobbies, preferred channel, marital status, credit risk (low, medium, high), education status, etc. If I convert each of these variable in to dummies and run kmeans, I would  be having 90 columns (30*3 - assuming each variable has 4 factors). Is this correct?

Comment: The question as currently worded is about the algorithmic details and not programming, so is off-topic here. You should post this in https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: As a side note, have you tried encoding the categorical data and then applying the usual clustering techniques? Maybe those can perform well on your data?

Comment: Have a look at the k-modes algorithm or Gower distance matrix.

Comment: @VivekKumar sure will post it there

Comment: @user2974951 In kmodes , how to determine the number of clusters available? and can you please explain how to calculate gower distance and use it for clustering

Comment: Search for the relevant libraries in python that will do this for you and you won't have to worry about the details of how to.

Comment: @VivekKumar: please do *not* encourage posting duplicates.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am sorry, but I do not understand. Are you saying about my comment to post this on stats.stackexchange.com? or the second one. I did not want to encourage posting duplicates and downvoted this.

Comment: Your first comment encourages posting the same question there. Please suggest to "move", "migrate", etc. the next time. And consider suggesting to use search there: the duplicate there was closed... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Overlap-based similarity measures* (**k-modes**), *Context-based similarity measures* and many more listed in the paper [Categorical Data Clustering](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4899-7687-1_35) will be a good start. Since you already have experience and knowledge of k-means than **k-modes** will be easy to start with.

Comment: Thanks,Is there any method available to determine the number of clusters in Kmodes

Comment: Do you have a label that you can use as unique to determine the number of clusters ? If not than is all based on domain knowledge or you specify a random number of clusters to start with ...

Comment: Other approach is to use hierarchical clustering on Categorical Principal Component Analysis, this can discover/provide info on how many clusters you need (this approach should work for the text data too). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, You can try LSKkRepresentatives from pypi here:
https://pypi.org/project/lshkrepresentatives/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use mixture of multinomial distriubtions.

The number of cluster can be selected with information criteria (e.g., BIC, ICL...).

If you can use R, then use the R package VarSelLCM which implements this approach.